# Using NOT in Regex in replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
String a = "$$bar$55^$$";
```

I want remove all symbols. I make regex:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("(?<=[^[\\p{Alpha}][\\p{Digit}]])", "");
```

But, I get:

```
$$bar$55^$$
```

But I want to get this string:

```
bar55
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I filter out all characters except letters and numbers?

In `Oracle` it work for me:

```
select regexp_replace('$$bar$55^$$','[^[:alpha:][:digit:]]*') from dual;
```

Comment: Just a note: `[[:alpha:]]` can be translated as `\p{Alpha}`, not `[\\p{Alpha}]`. POSIX character classes can only be used inside bracket expressions (Oracle uses a POSIX regex engine), and shorthand character classes in Java regex do not have to be wrapped with `[...]` individually. Also, `[[:alpha:][:digit:]]` = `[[:alnum:]]`. Hence, I suggest `\P{Alnum}` to match any chars other than alphanumeric. Although you also may use `"[^\\p{Alpha}\\p{Digit}]+"`. No need for the nested character classes and the resulting union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a lookaround that is a non-consuming pattern, i.e. the match value will always be empty since only a location inside a string will be matched. Use

```
String b = a.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "");
```

The `\\P{Alnum}+` pattern matches one or more chars other than ASCII alphanumeric chars. Also, see [Predefined Character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc).

Alternatively, you may use

```
String b = a.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{P}\\p{S}]+", "");
```

This will remove chunks of 1 or more chars other than Unicode letters, punctuation and symbols.

Comment: FYI, see [the Java demo online](https://ideone.com/JgbBOi). `"$$bar$55^$$".replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "")` yields `bar55`.